# How to select multiple values from JSON array

Tags: sql, arrays, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have sample data like below, I want to display all project names, and not just one by passing index because the size of array is not known in every column.

By trying below SQL getting only 'project1'. Need both project1 and project2 in concatenation.

```
WITH dataset AS 
(
   SELECT '{"name": "Bob Smith",
             "org": "engineering",
             "projects": [{"name":"project1", "completed":false},{"name":"project2", "completed":true}]}'
     AS myblob
)
SELECT json_extract_scalar(myblob, '$.projects[0].name') AS project_name
FROM dataset
```

Expecting like both project1 and project2 in concatenation.

```
project_name
project1,project2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple options. For example you can use the [`json_query`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json-query) which has better JSON path support than `json_extract`:

```sql
SELECT json_query(myblob, 'lax $.projects[*].name' WITH  ARRAY WRAPPER) projects
FROM dataset;
```

Output:

```
        projects
-------------------------
 ["project1","project2"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!. But When Im trying with data getting this error- Cannot read input of type json as JSON using formatting JSON.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PavanAithal This query worked for me on the provided sample data. Note that unlike `json_extract` `json_query` can't work with JSON type, only with VARCHAR. You can try calling `json_format` on your column first.